# paypal solutiontype=sole

Tags: paypal

I have a site that directs my customer to paypal express checkout.  I want to give guest the option to pay without creating a paypal account.  I have 2 variables to the paypal SetExpressCheckout API call but can't figure out where to place it in my code.  Can someone help me with this?

variables and values:

SOLUTIONTYPE = sole
LANDINGPAGE = billing

The Code:

```
<?php

/**
 * PayPal class
 */
class PayPal
{
    var $version = "64";

    /**
     * Wether or not use Sandbox mode
     */
    var $sandbox = false;

    /**
     * The API credentials
     */
    var $api_username;
    var $api_password;
    var $api_signature;

    /**
     * The API endpoint and the URL for non-sandbox integration
     */
    var $api_endpoint = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';
    var $paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=';

    /**
     * Proxy settings
     */
    var $use_proxy = false;
    var $proxy_host = '127.0.0.1';
    var $proxy_port = 808;

    /**
     * BN Code is only applicable for partners
     */
    var $bncode = "PP-ECWizard";

    /**
     * Some private keys
     */
    private $_token;
    private $_payerId;
    private $_currency = 'EUR';
    private $_paymentType = 'Sale';
    private $_resArray = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param string $api_username
     * @param string $api_password
     * @param string $api_signature
     */
    public function __construct($api_username, $api_password, $api_signature) {

        $this->api_username = $api_username;
        $this->api_password = $api_password;
        $this->api_signature = $api_signature;
    }

    /**
     * Set Sandbox status
     */
    public function useSandbox() {

        $this->sandbox = true;
        $this->api_endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
        $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=';
    }

    /**
     * When using a proxy server, set the host and port
     * @param string $host
     * @param integer $port
     */
    public function useProxy($host, $port=808) {

        if(!empty($host) && !empty($port) && is_numeric($port)) {

            $this->use_proxy = true;
            $this->proxy_host = $host;
            $this->proxy_port = (integer) $port;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new BN ocde
     */
    public function setBNcode($bncode=null) {

        $this->bncode = $bncode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the currency used for the order
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency='EUR') {

        $this->_currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * The type of payment is done here
     */
    public function setPaymentType($type='Sale') {

        $this->_paymentType = $type;
    }

    /**
     * An express checkout transaction starts with a token, that
     * identifies to PayPal your transaction
     * In this example, when the script sees a token, the script
     * knows that the buyer has already authorized payment through
     * paypal. If no token was found, the action is to send the buyer
     * to PayPal to first authorize payment
     * 
     * Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
     * 
     * @param string $paymentAmount:        Total value of the shopping cart
     * @param string $returnURL:            the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
     * @param string $cancelURL:            the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    */
    function shortcutExpressCheckout($paymentAmount, $returnURL, $cancelURL) 
    {
        // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation
        $nvpstr = '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='. $paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.$this->_paymentType;
        $nvpstr .= '&RETURNURL='.$returnURL;
        $nvpstr .= '&CANCELURL='.$cancelURL;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.$this->_currency;

        // Make the API call to PayPal
        // If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.
        // If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        $resArray = $this->_hashCall('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpstr);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

        if($ack == 'SUCCESS' || $ack == 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING') {
            $this->_token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        }
        else {
            throw new PayPal_Exception($resArray['L_ERRORCODE0'].': '.$resArray['L_SHORTMESSAGE0'].', '.$resArray['L_LONGMESSAGE0']);
        }

        // save result
        $this->_resArray = $resArray;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a token for confirm purposes
     * @param string $token
     */
    public function setToken($token) {

        if(!empty($token)) {

            $this->_token = $token;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the token set for the current payment
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToken() {

        return $this->_token;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the payer id for confirm purposes
     * @param string $payerid
     */
    public function setPayer($payerid) {

        if(!empty($payerid)) {

            $this->_payerId = $payerid;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the result array set for the current payment
     * @return array
     */
    public function getResult() {

        return $this->_resArray;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
     *
     * @param string $paymentAmount:    The total payment amount.
     * @return object The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
     */
    function confirm($paymentAmount)
    {
        // Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls
        $serverName = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

        $nvpstr = '&TOKEN='.urlencode($this->_token);
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYERID='.urlencode($this->_payerId);
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.$this->_paymentType;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.$paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.$this->_currency;
        $nvpstr .= '&IPADDRESS='.$serverName; 

        // Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
        // if an error occured, show the resulting errors
        $resArray = $this->_hashCall('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $nvpstr);

        $this->_resArray = $resArray;
    }

    /**
     * Function to perform the API call to PayPal using API signature
     * @param string $methodName:   is name of API  method.
     * @param string $nvpStr:       is nvp string.
     * @return array containing the response from the server.
     */
    private function _hashCall($methodName, $nvpStr)
    {
        // setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // turning off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // if use_proxy set to TRUE, then only proxy will be enabled. 
        if($this->use_proxy) {

            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy_host.':'.$this->proxy_port); 
        }

        // NVPRequest for submitting to server
        $nvpreq = 'METHOD='.urlencode($methodName);
        $nvpreq .= '&VERSION='.urlencode($this->version);
        $nvpreq .= '&PWD='.urlencode($this->api_password);
        $nvpreq .= '&USER='.urlencode($this->api_username);
        $nvpreq .= '&SIGNATURE='.urlencode($this->api_signature);
        $nvpreq .= $nvpStr.'&BUTTONSOURCE='.urlencode($this->bncode);

        // setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        // getting response from server
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
        $nvpResArray = $this->_deformatNVP($response);
        $nvpReqArray = $this->_deformatNVP($nvpreq);

        // Execute the Error handling module to display errors.
        if(curl_errno($ch)) {

            $error = curl_error($ch);
            throw new PayPal_Exception($error);
        } 
        // closing the curl
        else {

            curl_close($ch);
        }

        return $nvpResArray;
    }

    /**
     * This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response.
     * It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays.
     * @param string $nvpstr is NVPString.
     * @return array $nvpArray is Associative Array.
     **/
    private function _deformatNVP($nvpstr)
    {
        $intial = 0;
        $nvpArray = array();

        while(strlen($nvpstr)) {
            // postion of Key
            $keypos = strpos($nvpstr, '=');

            // position of value
            $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr, '&') : strlen($nvpstr);

            // getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array
            $keyval = substr($nvpstr, $intial, $keypos);
            $valval = substr($nvpstr, $keypos+1, $valuepos-$keypos-1);

            // decoding the respose
            $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] = urldecode($valval);
            $nvpstr = substr($nvpstr, $valuepos+1, strlen($nvpstr));
        }

        return $nvpArray;
    }

    /**
     * Redirects to PayPal.com site.
     */
    public function redirect() {

        $url = $this->paypal_url.$this->_token;
        header("Location: ".$url);
        exit();
    }
}

class PayPal_Exception extends Exception
{
    // Redefine the exception so message isn't optional
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0) {

        // make sure everything is assigned properly
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }

    // custom string representation of object
    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whatever class library this is you're using seems very limited in what it can do with Express Checkout. It's basically using the bare minimum options to make it work.

Your `shortcutExpressCheckout()` is only acccepting 3 parameters:  `$paymentAmount`, `$returnURL`, and `$cancelURL`. There is a whole lot more that can go into this, including the options you're trying to pass in.

Within that function, they're generating the NVP string and assigning it to the $nvpstr variable.  This is where you need to add your new parameters to get the desired effect.

Try this...

```
// Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation
$nvpstr = '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='. $paymentAmount;
$nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.$this->_paymentType;
$nvpstr .= '&RETURNURL='.$returnURL;
$nvpstr .= '&CANCELURL='.$cancelURL;
$nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.$this->_currency;
$nvpstr .= '&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing';
```

That should do it for you...all I did was add that last line to this chunk of code.

For future reference, you may be interested in taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It's much more complete than this one you're using, and it's very simple to use.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried doing what you suggested but when i get to the paypal page, it still ask me to create a paypal account. won't let me pay as a guest.

Comment: Need to also make sure the PayPal Account Optional option is enabled in your PayPal profile.  I think it's under Website Payment Preferences.

Comment: Output $ntpstr to the screen so we can see the entire value getting generated.  Need to double check that it's getting generated the way we're expecting.  I use Express Checkout with Guest Checkout all the time, and those are the only steps required, so we must be missing something somewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrew! it's working http://screencast.com/t/PmfJ20hi but after I log into my paypal and click continue, it doesn't take me to the page where shipping is calculated.  Is there another chunk of code that I need to add? Tried calling paypal but they are close.

Comment: After you login and review the order, clicking continue will send you back to the ReturnURL specified in SetExpressCheckout.  This is where you'd call GetExpressCheckoutDetails to get the payer's shipping address and calculate shipping based on that.  You can show a final review including shipping/tax prior to calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  You could also use the Instant Update API to send shipping options to the PayPal review page, but that's a little more involved and really doesn't work all that well.

Comment: Can you show me where to add the GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment call? I am completely lost with php :(

Comment: Well, I kinda said that in my previous comment.  You set a ReturnURL in your SetExpressCheckout request.  This is where the user will be returned when they're done with the PayPal review.  This would typically be a page/script that makes the GetExpressCheckoutDetails call and/or DoExpressCheckoutPayment to finalize everything.  You might have a review of your own in between those, though, in which case you'd call GECD to obtain the buyer's shipping info, then display a review page that includes shipping, tax, etc. and then when they submit that you'd call DECP to finalize everything.